# Spaces and special characters in URL - django

Tags: python, django

My URL is as follows:

```
test/One%20**&**%20Two/edit
```

Django URLs:

```
r'^(?P<test>[\w\-]+)/(?P<text>[\w\s]+)/edit/$'
```

Can anyone tell me why Django is not able to display page? I see Page not found (404).

Comment: May be about the last back slash on pattern?

Comment: There are many things wrong with your urlpattern. To start with, it won't match `%20**&**%20`. Please go through the [official Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) to get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to capture all this garbage into the second group, just use:

`^(?P<test>[\w\-]+)/(?P<text>.+)/edit/?$`

... and I'm not even asking why you're willing to do so (: